# There's something wrong with using XLPagerTabStrip

Tags: swift, xlpagertabstrip

I did everything in [XLPagerTabStrip Usage](https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip#usage)

But there is something wrong :(

```
2016-05-21 20:36:53.108 [13794:5338746] the behavior of the 
UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because:
2016-05-21 20:36:53.109 [13794:5338746] the item height must 
be less than the height of the UICollectionView minus the 
section insets top and bottom values, minus the content insets 
top and bottom values.
2016-05-21 20:36:53.109 [13794:5338746] Please check the values 
return by the delegate.
2016-05-21 20:36:53.110 [13794:5338746] The relevant 
UICollectionViewFlowLayout instance is <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x137c836e0>, 
and it is attached to <XLPagerTabStrip.ButtonBarView: 0x13715ec00; 
baseClass = UICollectionView; frame = (0 66; 375 45); 
clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; 
gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x137c82f30>; 
layer = <CALayer: 0x137c64ff0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; 
contentSize: {239.5, 128}> collection view layout: 
<UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x137c836e0>.
2016-05-21 20:36:53.110 [13794:5338746] Make a symbolic breakpoint 
at UICollectionViewFlowLayoutBreakForInvalidSizes to catch 
this in the debugger.
```

I can't find any solution.
Is there somebody know this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip/issues/162
this is exactly same problem, and I solved my problem just like that link.